# Alter Datetime format in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to modify date format in date column of a python dataframe 'df' from 06/01/2018 to 06-01-2018.

I tried the following but did not work.

```
df['date'].str.replace('/','-')
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the string? Or turn a true date time object into a string? Or try to turn a string into a date time?

Comment: What do you mean "did not work"? `…str.replace` will return a new Series, not modify the existing one.

Comment: Also, is your date column in `datetime64` format, `str` format, `object` format holding Python `datetime.datetime` objects, or…? If it's anything but `str`, it doesn't _have_ a format; it's storing a datetime as a datetime value, and you can format it however you want each time you print it.

Comment: @abarnert - Thank you that was a silly mistake. I was not assigning df['date'].str.replace('/','-') to df['date'] hence it was not being saved. Date column is in datetime format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_datetime` and access `strftime` using `dt`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["06/01/2018"]})
print( pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") )
```

**Output:**

```
0    06-01-2018
Name: data, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, this worked. Also, I realized that I was not assigning df['date'].str.replace('/','-') to df['date'] hence it was not being saved. Nevertheless, I learned a new way to achieve this.